# Como validar campos com o Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Tenho uma tela que precisa validar 2 campos. Caso uma ou ambas receba valores errados, me retorna um `snackbar` com a mensagem do erro. Porém, gostaria de deixar o campo em vermelho, assim que retornar a snackbar, mas, não consigo fazer esse retorno.

```
TextFormField(
                                // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                                
                                controller: _emailController,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                                      Icons.mail_outline,
                                      color: greenColor,
                                    ),
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                     
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                    ),
                                    labelText: 'E-mail'),
                                
                                validator: (email) {
                                  if (!emailValid(email))
                                    return _errorSnackBar(errorEmail);
                                  return null;
                                },
                              )
```

Agora com apenas uma mensagem de erro no `return` a barra destorce completamente
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O validator do TextFormField não serve apenas para deixar a barra vermelha, ele fica menor porque obrigatoriamente você deveria informar uma mensagem de erro no próprio componente e não mostrar uma SnackBar, esse é o comportamento original.

Você retorna null se a validação passou e retorna o erro, uma String, caso não passou.

validator: (String value){
if(value.isEmpty) return "O campo está vazio!";
else return null;
}

Você tem duas opções:

- Modo padrão, mostrar apenas o erro no próprio componente, removendo a SnackBar.
- Usando validação externa, colocando seu TextFormField dentro de um Container e dando um border pra ele, trocando dinamicamente a cor desse border caso tenha um erro, isso é mais trabalhoso porque praticamente você fará a funcionalidade do TextFormField na mão.